# Setting an initial location to JFrame, using "super" keyword

Tags: java, jframe

I'm having trouble setting an initial location for a "turtle" (actually a triangle) to the screen using Method overloading. I am meant to call the Turtle in the new Dynamicturtle constructor using the super keyword, then set the position of the turtle from the new arguments of the new dynamic turtle constructor, then draw the turtle. A hint was given to use the move methods to achieve this?

It will then create a new Dynamicturtle variable and instantiate it in the main class, and it will draw the turtle to the JFrame. I am completely stuck on how to achieve this - what seems a simple problem. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

The Main class.

```js
import javax.swing.*;

class Lab5
{
 public static void main(String [ ] args)
 {
  JFrame frame = new JFrame();
  Canvas canvas = new Canvas();
  frame.setTitle("Hello Frame");
  frame.setSize(800, 600);
  frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
  frame.setVisible(true);
  frame.add(canvas);
  int deltaTime = 20; // milliseconds
  // game loop
  
  Dyanmicturtle jig = new Dyanmicturtle(canvas, 400, 300);
  jig.drawTurtle();

  while(true)
  {
  Utils.pause(deltaTime);
  }
 }
}
```

DynamicTurtle class:

```js
class DynamicTurle extends Turtle
{
 private int speed = 100;
 private int time;
 private double xPos, yPos;
 private CartesianCoordinate myLocation;
 private int Angle = 0;

 DynamicTurle(Canvas canvas, CartesianCoordinate initLocation)
 {
  super(canvas, initLocation);
  this.drawTurtle();
 }

 DynamicTurle(Canvas canvas, double xPosition, double yPosition) //THE PROBLEM CONSTRUCTOR 
 {
  super(canvas, newPosition);
  CartesianCoordinate newPosition = new CartesianCoordinate (this.xPosition, this.yPosition);   
  this.drawTurtle();
 }


 public int getSpeed()
 {
  return this.speed;
 }

 public void setSpeed(int speed)
 {
  this.speed = speed;
 }

 public void update(int time)
 {
  this.unDrawTurtle();
  this.move((speed*100/time)); 
  this.drawTurtle();
 }
}
```

The Turtle class:

```js
class Turtle 
{
    private Canvas canvas; // private field reference to a canvas private           
    private CartesianCoordinate myLocation, oldLocation; 
    private boolean penDown = true;
    private double Angle;
    public Turtle kieranMullen;

    public Turtle(Canvas canvas, CartesianCoordinate initLocation) 
    {
        this.canvas = canvas;
        this.myLocation = new CartesianCoordinate(0,0);
        Angle = 0;
        penDown = true;
        myLocation = initLocation.copy();        
    }

    public void putPenUp() 
    {
       this.penDown = false; 
    }

    public void putPenDown() 
    {
        this.penDown = true; 
    }   

    public void turn(double amount) 
    {
       Angle = Angle + amount; 
    }
    

    public void move(int pixels) 
    {
        double radians = Math.toRadians(Angle);
        double dx = pixels * Math.sin(radians);
        double dy = pixels * Math.cos(radians);
        
        CartesianCoordinate oldLocation = myLocation.copy();
        
        myLocation.add(dx,dy);
        
        if(penDown)
        {
            canvas.drawLineBetweenPoints(myLocation, oldLocation);
        }
    }

    public void drawTurtle()
    {
        this.putPenDown();
        this.turn(90);
        this.move(10);
        this.putPenDown();
        this.turn(240);
        this.move(20);
        this.putPenDown();
        this.turn(240);
        this.move(20);
        this.putPenDown();
        this.turn(240);
        this.move(10);
        this.turn(270);       
    }

    public void unDrawTurtle()
    {
        canvas.removeMostRecentLine();
        canvas.removeMostRecentLine();
        canvas.removeMostRecentLine();
        canvas.removeMostRecentLine();
    }

    public void showSquare()
    {
        this.unDrawTurtle();
        Utils.pause(1000);
        this.drawTurtle();
        Utils.pause(1000);
        this.unDrawTurtle();
        this.move(100);
        this.drawTurtle();
        Utils.pause(1000);
        this.unDrawTurtle();  
        this.turn(90);
        this.drawTurtle();
        Utils.pause(1000);
        this.unDrawTurtle();
        this.move(100);
        this.drawTurtle();
        Utils.pause(1000);
        this.unDrawTurtle();  
        this.turn(90);
        this.drawTurtle();
        Utils.pause(1000);
        this.unDrawTurtle();
        this.move(100);
        this.drawTurtle();
        Utils.pause(1000);
        this.unDrawTurtle();  
        this.turn(90);
        this.drawTurtle();
        Utils.pause(1000);
        this.unDrawTurtle();
        this.move(100);
        this.drawTurtle();
        Utils.pause(1000);
        this.unDrawTurtle();  
        this.turn(90);
        this.drawTurtle();
        Utils.pause(1000);
        this.unDrawTurtle();         
    }
}
```

Thankyou for any help given in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Change the constructor to this:

```
DynamicTurle(Canvas canvas, double xPosition, double yPosition) {
    super(canvas, new CartesianCoordinate (xPosition, yPosition));
    this.drawTurtle();
}
```

---

Or even better, call your other constructor:

```
DynamicTurle(Canvas canvas, double xPosition, double yPosition) {
    this(canvas, new CartesianCoordinate (xPosition, yPosition));
}
```

Which avoids the repeated line of `this.drawTurtle();`

Comment: Thankyou! that compiled with no errors or run time errors, however, it does not draw the turtle to the canvas. Thankyou for your help! greatly appreciated!

Comment: My bad! I didn't save the main class before compiling, thanks so much Jorn!